# How can I avoid using for loops when applying a matrix to a column vector of coordinates?

Tags: matlab

```
C = 4.75000000000000,-2.59375000000000,1.34375000000000;-0.125000000000000,1.78125000000000,1.34375000000000;-0.250000000000000,-1.43750000000000,2.68750000000000]

samples = 10000;
[inx iny] = meshgrid(0:1/samples:1)
for i = 1:size(inx,1)
    for j = 1:size(iny,1)

    temp= C*[inx(i,j),iny(i,j),1]';

    outx(i,j) = temp(1)./temp(3);
    outy(i,j) = temp(2)./temp(3);

    end
end
```

The is my original code, it applies the matrix C to the column vector trans(inx iny 1) to produce a the vector trans(x' y' z').

Out_x = x'/z'; Out_y = y'/z';

The other way (faster) to do this is to manually expand the matrix C multiplication and write it out then apply it to the meshgrids inx and iny

```
        outx = (C(1,1)*inx+C(1,2)*iny+C(1,3))./(C(3,1).*inx+C(3,2).*iny+C(3,3));
    outy = (C(2,1).*inx+C(2,2).*iny+C(2,3))./(C(3,1).*inx+C(3,2).*iny+C(3,3));
```

Like that.

Is there anyway of writing that (using meshgrids) without having to manually multiply out my own matrices?

Any help welcome,

Comment: You should post to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, this isn't valid MATLAB code.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to transform your input coordinates `inx` and `iny` into a row vector. Then you can combine them with a third row of ones and apply your transformation multiplying by `C`. Last step, you have to transform back into a matrix with the same size as `inx`:

```
C = [4.75000000000000,-2.59375000000000,1.34375000000000;
  -0.125000000000000,1.78125000000000,1.34375000000000;
  -0.250000000000000,-1.43750000000000,2.68750000000000];

samples = 100;
sample_points = linspace(0, 1, samples);
[inx iny] = meshgrid(sample_points);

V = [inx(:)'; iny(:)'; ones(size(inx(:)'))];
T = C*V;
outx = reshape(T(1,:)./T(3,:), size(inx));
outy = reshape(T(2,:)./T(3,:), size(iny));
```

I tested the above code using Octave.

Last, if you want to be sure that you get a fixed number of samples, it is easier to use `linspace` instead of specifying the interval (as in `start:interval:end`). With your code you get 101 values when samples value is 100, I guess this is not what you intended.